# Реализация вознаграждения

Tags: android, разработка-игр, libgdx, admob

Я использую `LibGDX` и `AdMob`.

**У меня есть интерфейс:**

```
public interface AdService {

    void showRewarded();
    boolean rewardedVideoAdIsLoaded();

}
```

**AndroidLauncher.java:**

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdService{
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_REWARDED = "ca-app-pub-ХХХХХХХХХХХХХ/ХХХХХХХХХ";
protected RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new Game(this), config);


    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pubXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    rewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID_REWARDED, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
            rewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID_REWARDED, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void showRewarded() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded())
                rewardedVideoAd.show();
            else
                rewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID_REWARDED, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean rewardedVideoAdIsLoaded() {
    return rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded();
}
  }
```

Потом я вызываю `showRewarded()` в самой игре для отображения рекламы.

```
ad.addListener(new InputListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                  game.adService.showRewarded();
            }
        });
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии рекламы начислялся бонус за просмотр?

Answer (score 3):

Так есть же метод OnAdClosed, он вызываеться при закрытии, но перед этим проверь посмотрел ли он видео, полностью, для этого закинь булевую переменную в OnAdRewarded

Comment: Имеешь ввиду этот метод public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() ? Я пытался с помощью него делать? Но я не понял как это реализовать. При закрытии рекламы, этот метод должен, к примеру, умножать монеты на 2 и передавать обратно в core модель, где и написан весь код игры. Я не совсем понял как это сделать.

Comment: @Алексей так нужно еще добавить при создании в начале rewardedVideoAd.OnAdClosed += OnRewardedVideoAdClosed(), и этот метод будет вызываться при закрытии

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы начислялся бонус, желательно давать его не при закрытии, а при вызове метода `onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem)`, потому что бывают случаи, когда видео можно закрыть до его окончания (так юзер получит монеты, а вы не получите деньги).

Также вы в комментарии спросили, как увеличивать монеты, если они в модуле `core`. Всё просто, каждый модуль платформы имеет у себя в зависимости core, то есть вы можете видеть и использовать классы с модуля `core`.

Вы, например, можете сохранить лаунчер из `core` модуля в поле класса:

```
...
private Game gameLauncher;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gameLauncher = new Game(this);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(gameLauncher, config);
    ...
}
```

А затем общаться через него, пример:

```
...
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    gameLauncher.getUser().giveCoins(количествоМонет);
}
...
```